# PreFast in VS 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, prefast

Which version of VS 2010 has PreFast static code analyzer for native c++? I have downloaded VS 2010 Ultimate edition trial version in hope that it would contain all the features, but could not found inbuilt PreFast in it. 
I tried to link VS 2010 to set it directories with WDK's PreFast and add "/analyze" in comand Line additional options but unable to get results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's in ultimate (I just tested it), but I don't think it's in pro.

help page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385907.aspx

Comment: and related stackoverflow Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888303/prefast-with-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Hey thanks steelbytes for response, I had gone through the link provided by you and checked the rules available. But I was looking for some memory leakage, thread dead locks kind of rules. Are they available in PreFast or should look for third party tools ?

Comment: my guess:  deadlocks? no prefast won't find them.  no tool will :-(  and memory leaks, maybe some simple ones, but not most.  it's better at things like buffer overflows

Answer (score 1):

> I was looking for some memory leakage, thread dead locks kind of rules.

Prefast is static analysis tool. It checks for possible `NULL` derefferensing, buffer overruns and such. You are looking for dynamic analysis tool like Bounds Checker. Not sure, that it is available for  VS 2010. Another option would be to use Application Verifyer.